# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit"

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, fbsdkloginkit

I'm making use of `flutter_login_facebook 1.0.1` plugin to enable logging into my app using Facebook.

I'm getting the below error when trying to set up Facebook login on an iOS device.

```
 pod install
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `FirebaseFirestore` from `https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`, tag `8.0.0`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      FBSDKLoginKit (~> 11.0.0)

    flutter_login_facebook (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_login_facebook/ios`) was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
      FBSDKLoginKit (~> 9.1)
```

I have tried the below steps that I could find from other posts on stackoverflow but no luck with it:

1. Deleted `Pods` folder, `ios/Podfile` file and `ios/Podfile.lock` file.
2. Executed `flutter clean` command.
3. Executed `flutter pub get` command.
4. Tried updating using the following commands `pod update FBSDKCoreKit`, `pod update FBSDKLoginKit` and `pod repo update`.
5. Excuted `pod install`

Below are the contents of my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.0.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Please find below details about my flutter and dart version:

```
Flutter 2.2.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d79295af24 (4 weeks ago) • 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
Engine • revision 91c9fc8fe0
Tools • Dart 2.13.3
```

Could anyone please help me in getting this issue fixed. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: According to the error message you provide you can try  `$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pod install`  in your terminal

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's a warning.

Comment: Could you add your podfile.lock file also to the question and also .yaml file

Comment: Sorry I have deleted that file.

Comment: you can update with pod repo update or with pod install --repo-update. After that let ne know the result. You should  run these commands on ios directory.

Comment: Hi, how did you resolve this .  I am having similar problem and can't find any help in the net?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the **Podfile.lock** and running **pod install --repo-update** solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using an up-to-date version of Flutter and `flutter_login_facebook` plugin. Then run `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the references. Alternatively, you can delete pubspec.lock before running `flutter pub get` to fetch the dependencies.